# How can I resolve an ILP (integral linear programming) model whose system matrix is 1187550*391275?

Tags: matlab, integral, large-scale

I tried lingo software. More than 100 hours passed, I haven't get the result.

I tried MATLAB software. When I run this code "A=zeros (1187550,391275)" it occurs error: The biggest variable values beyond the program allows

So, is there some good ways to solve this large-scale matrix model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You gave it a multiplication. So it gets the result and tries to create a square matrix with as much rows and columns as the result.

what you want is

```
A=zeros(1187550,391275)
```

Next time try `help $command$` to get an explanation for the function in matlab

or `doc $command` for the documentation

edit:

You also need 3.5TB of RAM for that as

`1187550*391275*64bit/8(bit per byte)/1024(byte per kB)/1024(kB per MB)/1024(MB per GB) = 3462GB`.

I guess you dont have that much^^

So you should break it down to partial solutions if possible. And if it suits you, you can also use another datatype to reduce the needed memory (single/float would cut it in half).

This problem should be present in any other program as long it allocates the memory for the whole Matrix at once.

Comment: Yeah, The code is "A=zeros(1187550,391275)".  I'm sorry for my writing error. It always occur the error "Maximum variable size allowed by the program is exceeded"

Comment: next thing is you need approx 3.5TB of ram for that as  1187550*391275*64bit/8 (bit per byte)/1024(to kB)/1024(to MB)/1024(to GB) is 3462GB. So you should do partial solutions if possible.

Comment: yes, it is a so large scale matrix, it is thorny. Thanks for you answer and help. I may simplify my model first

Comment: If you like the answer you may upvote it and or mark it as the solution